# Safari 6.0 (8536.25) CSS Bug (strange background/selection color bug on dropdown menu)

Tags: safari

Using Safari 6.0 (8536.25).

This "bug" does not present in Firefox, or Chrome, only in Safari.

I am seeing a very strange color (cannot determine if this is a css background color, a css selection color, or something OS related) on my navigation. This only happens in Safari, and it seems to be "consistent" in that the "color" always appears in the same area.

I can't pinpoint where this is coming from via the Web Inspector.

Here is the url: http://project1989.com/development/RAD/

Also, here is a Screenshot in case noone else sees the "bug".

Safari: http://cl.ly/image/1c0b2T380v1C

Can anyone else re-produce this bug, and/or give any insight into what's causing it?

I wrote all the css myself, so I'm puzzled as to where it comes from, I can confirm that before upgrading to Safari 6.0, everything worked fine.

Thanks!

PS, I deleted these lines from my css, because I thought they were causing the issue, but it didn't fix anything. These *are* in my css however-

```
::selection {
    background: #04C4FB; /* Safari */
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #04C4FB; /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what the problem is as I can't tell from looking at your links?

Comment: If you see the Screenshot I attached, the problem are the "blue boxes" on the navigation (for example behind "blog" and to the left of "artwork"). Nothing in my css should be causing this (there shouldn't be any blue boxes, only the text color should change). If you open the link to the site in FF/Chrome you will see how it *should* look, then look at the screenshot again to see the issue. Thanks!

Comment: PS, sorry if the original description of the problem is vague, it's a pretty strange issue, and a bit hard to explain.

Comment: *ALSO* - This bug is present in WebKit nightly build. It seems to actually be influenced by the size (width) of the browser window. Ex- if you shrink browser window the "color" appears in different areas than when the browser window is wider. I wish I could record a video capture of this bug in action. It's very weird.

Comment: Here's another screenshot showing comment above. On the top half is how it looks when browser is narrow, on the bottom is full width. Notice how the position of the "color" moves http://cl.ly/image/0U370N1S3v1o

Comment: Hmm, even stranger. Apparently the colors do not show up after I brought the screenshots into Photoshop and saved them as png (on last attached screenshot). Could this bug be due to my monitor calibration settings?

Comment: That's good, I thought I was having trouble with my eyes as I still can't see your problem :p

Comment: I call color profile shenanigans.

Comment: So strange, look at this screenshot! In the PS "save for web" box, I can't see the colors but in the Photoshp document beneath they are still there... wth ?   Does anyone else see this is or it just me? http://cl.ly/image/3k3z0w3c0M0l

Comment: I think BoltClock is right... Would this explain why it only displays in Safari? PS, don't think I'm crazy, I have a strange suspicion noone else can see what I'm talking about and I look like a loon.

Comment: @skisloski: I see the color in that last screenshot you posted (in both Photoshop and the browser). My guess is you're saving the image out from Photoshop with the incorrect color in there, but it's so close that you can't see it until you view the page in Safari, which uses a different color profile.

Comment: @daGUY Thanks, I agree that it has something to do with my color profile. *But*, I saved all of these image assets on the site prior to switching to this computer/os/color-profile/safari version, so I don't know why I'm just seeing it now. I guess it would be nice to know if other people are seeing the bug on the actual site or not. Either way, thanks.

Comment: Also, I've tried a few other color profiles via system preferences > displays... and I still see this "bug" with those. Maybe I need to restart Safari to render w the new profile?

Comment: I don't think you need to restart Safari. Are you saving "for web" from Photoshop?

Comment: @skisloski: "I saved all of these image assets on the site prior to switching to this computer/os/color-profile/safari version, so I don't know why I'm just seeing it now." Right, but the original images in Photoshop have the wrong color in them, since I can see it on my monitor in the screenshot from Photoshop that you posted. Your current computer probably has a different color profile that now makes that wrong color visible to you.

Comment: @daGUY Yes, I am doing File > Save for Web. Thanks for your help, its appreciated

Comment: @daGUY One last thought on this. If it is my system color profile, why does it not display (at all) in Chrome or Firefox? It shows up in Webkit and Safari. Just a bit confused on that part. Also I will need to work on my workflow (ie. colorspaces) in Photoshop to make sure I'm not seeing things wrong. *Sigh* Having a built in monitor (iMac) had it's benefits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to a bug I reported regarding colour treatment in Safari 6. It only occurs on some systems, which is why this is tricky to reproduce. For example, I don't see this on my MacBook Air, but my old MacBook Pro (running the same build) shows the issue.

Since it's a rendering bug, as of right now, there is no workaround, as far as I can figure out.

Comment: Thanks! At least not too many other people will be seeing it. For reference, I'm running a Mac Pro w/ Mountain Lion, and Safari 6.0. I also have a Dell u2410 Monitor that I custom calibrated. I think that is what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'transform: translateZ(0)' to the element, it does the trick!
Hope I could help!